# Running infinite loop and getting commands from "outside" (e.g. shell or other scripts)

Tags: python

I am working on my Raspberry Pi, that is handling some WS2812B RGB-LEDs. I can control the light and everything with the neopixel library and Python. So fine right now.

I want this Python script running an infinite loop that only deals with light management. Dimming LEDs, changing color and lots more. But, I want to be able to get commands from other scripts. Let's say I want to type in a shell command that will change the color. In my infinite Python script (LED Handler), I will be able to recognize this command and change the color or the light mode softly  to the desired color.

One idea is, to constantly look into a text file, if there is a new command. And my shell script is able to insert command lines into this text file.

But can you tell me, if there is a better solution of doing it?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The socket suggestions below are the way to go.  The only thing I'd add is that if you don't need to receive these commands externally (if it's a script going to control them), you may want to consider using Unix Domain Sockets instead.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister Feel free to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method would be to expose a TCP server, then communicate with the Python process over TCP. A simple example on how to create a TCP server is here, showcasing both the server script (running the LEDs) and the command scripts: [example](https://gist.github.com/Integralist/3f004c3594bbf8431c15ed6db15809ae)

Comment: This one is very nice. Thank you so much. But I have one question. In your example, the call "server.accept()" blocks the script until a new client-connection is established. But I want to keep the main script ongoing. Is there something like a function with a returning value indicating if new data is available? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I suggest opening a port with your python script and make it receive commands from that port (network programming). Although this would make your project more complicated, it is a very robust implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) and host it locally. It provides [bindings for Python](https://pypi.org/project/pyzmq/). Here is an example script (sender and receiver):

```
from threading import Thread
import zmq


class Sender(Thread):
    def run(self):
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
        socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:8000')
        while True:
            socket.send_string(input('Enter command: '))


class Receiver(Thread):
    def run(self):
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        socket.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:8000')
        socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'')
        while True:
            data = socket.recv().decode('ascii')
            print(data)  # Do stuff with data.
```

The receiver would be the instance that controls the lights on the RPi and the sender is the command line script that let's you input the various commands. An advantage is that ZeroMQ supports [bindings for various programming languages](http://zeromq.org/bindings:_start) and you can also send/receive commands over a network.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to allow commands from a network connection. The script with the "infinite loop" will read input from a socket and perform the commands.